# Run GrassGIS API external on Python Shell Error module run None

Tags: python-2.7, failed-installation, grass

I am trying to run the GrassGIS modules on external python scripts on a ms windows server 2016 standard. What ever I do (experimenting with different installations of Grass, changing environmental variables, changing python code) - it won't run.

I have tried to run installation with OSGEO4W and standalone version. in 7.2 , 7.4 and 7.6 (7.6 unintentionally as it installed 7.6 despite reading 7.4
(svn checkout https://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass/branches/releasebranch_7_4 grass74_release >>on https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/wiki/DownloadSource).
I have also experimented with all different recommendations for environmental variables I found online - however, I cannot get it to run.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhEYA.jpg)

Any Help  - So much appreciated!!!!